# Integrating Dropbox with file managers other than Nautilus (GNOME Files)

Tags: dropbox, filemanager

Is it possible to integrate Dropbox in other file managers than nautilus? If yes, which manager would be best suited for this, and how do I set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the closed source Dropbox Linux client from http://www.getdropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86 (x86_64 for 64 bit)
2. Extract the contents and you should get a .dropbox-dist folder out of the archive. Move the folder to$HOME
3. Run~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd.

Reference: http://antrix.net/posts/2008/dropbox-without-gnome/

Comment: I'm at mobile, when I get home I can explain better if you need. ;-)

Comment: This works well (I use it on a kde desktop) but it might not qualify as "integrating" with another file manager.

Comment: Could you explain what is needed to qualify this as integrating?

Comment: An autosyncing folder is enough. thanks, the article is pretty clear on the steps to take.

Comment: Welcome. If others functions are missing tell me then I can look toward it ;-)

Comment: as far as i know, there isn't a dropbox-thunar integration yet.

Comment: One function that I'm looking for is folder ribbons or something that tells me if a file has been uploaded or not. I'm using Nemo on Ubuntu and I really miss this feature